# Derivative of Integral-2 methods

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f$ be a bounded funvtion and let
$$g(t)=\int_0^\infty f(xt)dx$$
I want to calculate the derivative of $g$. I guess there are two ways to calculate it. Firstly by bounded convergence theorem
$$g'(t)=\int_0^\infty f'(xt)xdx$$
Also, I guess we ca do the following. Let $y=xt$. Then
$$g(t)=\int_0^\infty \frac{f(y)}{t}dy$$
then,
$$g'(t)=\int_0^\infty -\frac{f(y)}{t^2}dy$$
Are these two the same. I tried using integration by parts on the first equation. That gives
$$g'(t)=f(xt)\frac{x}{t}\bigg|_0^\infty-\int_0^\infty \frac{f(xt)}{t}dx$$. Can anyone please pont out where I am making the mistake?

Comment: Have you tried with a specific function that you can integrate, e.g. $f(y)=e^{-y}$ ?

Comment: I haven't tried any specific function. Are you suggesting that this is true only for some functions?

Comment: I'm just saying you might get some insight by checking all of your equations against something that you can compute. If it holds for some examples, you can try to generalize.

Answer (score 2):

Both your expressions for $g'(t)$ are equal as they must.

Hint: The integral $$g(t)=\int_0^\infty f(xt)\,dx$$ is only defined when $f$ vanishes at infinity.

Full Proof:

> From $$y=xt\,,\quad dy=t\,dx=\frac{y}{x}\,dx$$ we get using substitution and integration by parts \begin{align}g'(t)&=\int_0^\infty -\frac{f(y)}{t}\,dy=\int_0^\infty -\frac{x}{y}f(xt)\,\frac{y}{x}\,dx=-\int_0^\infty f(xt)\,dx\\[2mm]&=\int_0^\infty f'(xt)\,x\,dx+\underbrace{f(xt)\,x\Big|_{x=0}^{x=\infty}}_{0}\,.\end{align}